Integral of $\exp(\langle x, a+ib\rangle)$ over hypersphere
I am looking to compute the following integral over $S_{n-1}$ the unit hypersphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{equation}
I(a,b) = \frac{1}{|S_{n-1}|}\int_{S_{n-1}}e^{\langle x,a+ib \rangle}dx
\end{equation}
for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and with $|S_{n-1}|$ the surface of $S_{n-1}$
It is known that $I(a,0)={}_{0}F_{1}(\frac{n}{2},\frac{\lVert a\lVert^2}{4})$ and $I(0,b)={}_{0}F_{1}(\frac{n}{2},-\frac{\lVert b\lVert^2}{4})$, which can be computed using the symmetry of the integrand in hyperspherical coordinates, but I couldn't find a way to proceed in the general case. Is there a closed form or an asymptotic for $n\to\infty$ ?
Any help would be much appreciated !

I will tackle the integral on the sphere of radius $r$:
$$J(\mathbf{z},r)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}e^{\mathbf{z}\cdot x}\delta(||x||-r)d^n x,~~ \mathbf{z}\in \mathbb{C}^n$$
The answer to this integral bears similarity to the answers for purely real and imaginary vectors respectively, but it seems to require stronger tools for its computation. One way to go about this to consider the following quantity
$$Q(\mathbf{z}, s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-sr^2}J(\mathbf{z},r)dr=\mathcal{L}_s\left(\frac{J(\mathbf{z},\sqrt{t})}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$
Since it is related to a Laplace transformation, if we manage to compute $Q$ we can in principle compute its inverse to find the integral we are interested in. Indeed, $Q$ is now just a product of Gaussian integrals:
$$Q(\mathbf{z}, s)=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{s^{n/2}}\exp\left(\frac{\lambda}{4s}\right),~~\lambda:=\sum_{k=1}^n z_k^2$$
A lookup in Laplace transform tables reveals that the inverse transform is
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}_t(Q(\mathbf{z}, s))=\pi^{n/2}\left(\frac{4t}{\lambda}\right)^{n/4-1/2}I_{n/2-1}(\sqrt{\lambda t})$$
which after a bit of algebra yields the answer for the integral in question:
$$J(\mathbf{z},r)=\frac{(2\pi r)^{n/2}}{(\sum z_k^2)^{n/4-1/2}}I_{n/2-1}\left(r\sqrt{\sum z_k^2}\right)$$

Brilliantly elegant, thank you !

It seems there is a slight typo, I believe the denominator in the final solution should be $\sqrt{\sum z_k^2}^{n/2-1}$

corrected the typo!
